# Autenticação Basic SoapClient PHP

Tags: php, laravel, web-service, soap, autenticação-http

Estou tentando conectar a um *web-service* usando **Soapclient**, toda via ele requisita usuário e senha para tal conexão. segue a forma que estou tentando conectar:

```
$wsdl = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX?WSDL";
$options = array(
"login" => $username,
"password" => $password,
"authentication" => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC,
"location" => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
"trace" => true,
"exceptions" => 0,
"cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE);

$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
```

Comment: Para fazer requisições no Laravel, te recomento usar o [guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) e não `SoapClient()`

Comment: @ErlonCharles recomenda algum site ou documentação!?

Comment: Se o guzzle não estiver já instalado no seu laravel você pode apenas importar o pacore e utilizar usa documentação padrão, **pacote** => https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle **documentação** => http://guzzlephp.org/

Comment: @ErlonCharles tentamos com o guzzle, ele aparentemente da sucesso, porém eu não consigo acessar aos métodos, aparentemente falta um arquivo (.xsd) na requisição

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $client = new SoapClient(null, array('trace' => 1,
                'exceptions' => 0,
                'header' => xxxxxx,
                'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
                'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
                'uri' => XXXXX,
                'location' =>'XXXXXX',
                'login' =>'XXXX', 'password' =>'XXXXX'
        ));
```